# Can access Apache via IP but not domain with SSL

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, owncloud

I have a OwnCloud install, i'd like just https to be available and not http. So I've installed Lets Encrypt which installed fine. I've had already altered the apache conf to the attached below. I have a forward on our router for port 443. If I browse to https://IP it works, but I get an ssl warning which is normal as lets encrypt pulled the domain from the serverName config for apache. If I go to https://files.domain.org.uk I get a 404.

What could I be doing incorrectly?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName files.domain.org.uk

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =files.domain.org.uk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What happens if you change the VirtualHost directive port from 80 to 443 (top of file `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>`)? Essentially, you've declared a standard HTTP Vhost but not one for HTTPS so Apache doesn't know where to look to get your HTTPS content.

Comment: But if I browse to https://ExternalIP is serves the page, even with it set to port 80

Comment: How odd, it seems to be working now. If you put your comment in a answer i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Because your VirtualHost directive for Apache only contains a directive for HTTP requests (port 80) when you request an HTTPS (port 443) resource Apache will look at the directives and not be able to match one because you haven't declared one for port 443.

Changing `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>` will tell Apache that any request on port 443 that matches server name of **files.domain.org.uk** should look in your DocumentRoot for the scripts to display your site.

You may want to either keep the `<VirtualHost *:80>` directive if you want to be able to browse to http://files.domain.org.uk but receive a certificate warning, or keep your redirect from HTTP to HTTPS...